# Understanding the order of operations in an equation

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, mathematical-modeling

So I have an equation which I further need to program into R. But before starting the programming I need to understand what is actually happening in the equation and in what order it must be solved. As I am not a mathematician it is not obvious. The equation itself is a construction of an empirical copula $C_n$, where observed data is first transformed to uniform data on $[0,1]$ and then ranked to calculate $C_n$. Here is the equation (it is from Genest and Favre 2007):

$$
C_n(u_1i, u_2i, u_3i) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}I(\frac{R_i}{n+1}\leq u_1i, \frac{S_i}{n+1}\leq u_2i,\frac{T_i}{n+1}\leq u_3i)   
$$

where $n$ is a sample size, $I(A)$ denotes the indicator variable of the logical expression $A$ and takes the value of 0 if A is false. $C_n$ is a trivariate copula with three variables. The ranks of variables are represented as $R_i$, $S_i$ and $T_i$.

Questions:

I do not quite understand how the part $\frac{R_i}{n+1}\leq u_1i$ should be programmed and what it does. Does it compare the rank of every observation over samples size to original observation? And what is the role of $I$ and what happens if $I$ takes a value of zero? I would really appreciate if someone could bit by bit explain what is happening in this equation.Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you know why order of operations is important then ?

Comment: Well, it is important as otherwise, I get the wrong answer, right? In my case, due to the lack of experience with complex equations like this, I do not understand the order, especially in the part that is inside the brackets.

Comment: I'm not much help there but the order of operations is there so we get consistent answers and don't have arguments about what the answer is ( aka where the implied parentheses are) ex. without order of operations you get:

$1+2\cdot 3/4-5 = \{{-11\over4},{-10\over 4},\ldots\}$  where the number of possible answers depending on the expression could be as many as 24 or more. therefore we made conventions to follow.